# Origin of the strftime %c format field order in POSIX locale

Tags: history, unix, posix

In standard POSIX locale `strftime(buf, size, "%c", time)` will format the date and time in an order that has confused me a number of times because it has month and day precede the time, but year follow at the end. Example (from [ccpreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime)): `Sun Oct 17 04:41:13 2010`.

Since this appears to be a POSIX specification, the most canonical documentation I could find is this from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html:

> In the C or POSIX locale, […] the replacement strings for the following specifiers are:
> ⋮
> **`%c`** Equivalent to `%a %b %e %T %Y`.

I find this highly confusing, because putting the time between different parts of the date feels counter-intuitive to me (with a background in modern European conventions).

Some [ANSI C draft](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxVCLS4f8Sg5NWZmM2NjZWEtYmExMS00Y2EzLWE3ZTMtNzFmYjYwYzBiOTIw/view) referenced on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#External_links) suggests that

> `strftime` provides a way of formatting the date and time in the appropriate locale-
> specific fashion, using the `%c`, `%x`, and `%X` format specifiers. […] The facility is based on the UNIX system `date` command.

So apparently that is the next step back into history, even though the exact order of fields for default locale isn't specified in that document.

But why does the UNIX `date` binary do things that way?
Where did this come from?
How far back can this be traced?
Does this reflect everyday usage at the time and place, or was there a more technical reason for this format?

Some negative results:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States discusses date and time in isolation but not in combination.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country has only high-level overview, and only discusses date and time individually but not their combination.
- I looked at [Unicode CLDR v39](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-39) data but couldn't find any mention of such patterns. None of the XML files contain text that matches the regular expression `(hh|HH|KK|kk):mm.*yy` which is what I'd expect the time-then-year format to contain. The data again appears to describe date and time in isolation, not combination.
- [The C Programming Language](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition) by K&R 1st edition doesn't mention `strftime` yet.
- The `date` item in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time which has plenty of history for the binary representation but no content for the command line tool any more. As far as I can tell from history, there used to be a one-paragraph section on the command line tool with no historic background but that section got deleted.

Comment: Since I didn't sit on the POSIX Standards Committee I can't tell you with absolute certainty, but it appears that the Year was simply tacked onto the end of a Date/Time format that already existed.  `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S` forms a perfectly good date/time combination, if it happens to be *this* year.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this as "opinion-based" hasn't understood what that means -  obviously someone has made a decision about this in the past, this is an historical fact (maybe that decision itself was opinionated at that time, but that is not what that close reason is for).